# Can you do additional math on an aggregate value in a Django queryset

Tags: python, django, math, django-queryset

I am trying to avoid repeat aggregating on a value I have already calculated.  I am already getting an annual total, but I also want a quarterly total

What would work:

```py
django.db.models import Value

props_obj = PropertiesUsers.objects\
    .aggregate(returns_coc_a=Sum(F('subscribe_amount')
               * (F('deal_coc') / Value(100))),
               returns_coc_q=Sum(F('subscribe_amount')
               * (F('deal_coc') / Value(100))) / Value(4))
```

What I am trying to find out if/how I can do (reuse the annual amount):

```py
props_obj = PropertiesUsers.objects\
    .aggregate(returns_coc_a=Sum(F('subscribe_amount')
               * (F('deal_coc') / Value(100))),
               returns_coc_q=returns_coc_a / Value(4))
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  This feature is only available in v >= 1.8

Comment: Also, where is `Value` coming from?

Comment: Sorry, v=2.2.5, and Value is quarter (4/yr)..the other Value(100) is to make percent.

Comment: I mean where is `Value` defined?  AFAIK it isn't a part of Django or in the python standard library.  Is it from a 3rd party package?

Comment: If there isn't a simple way, I can always hand off the value to a custom tag and return separately.

Comment: from django.db.models import Value

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried searching the docs for `Value` and didn't get results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you assign annual aggregate to a variable and re-use it? like this:

```
django.db.models import F, Sum, Value

annual = Sum(F('subscribe_amount') * (F('deal_coc') / Value(100)))
quaterly = annual / Value(4)

props_obj = PropertiesUsers.objects\
    .aggregate(returns_coc_a=annual,
               returns_coc_q=quaterly)
```